# python sqlalchemy - count rows of result if plain sql query used

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using Python 3.9 together with sqlalchemy 1.4.18.

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///somedatabase.sqlite', echo=False)
query = """SELECT ...
    FROM ...
    LEFT JOIN ...
    WHERE ..."""
with engine.connect() as con:
    result = con.execute(query)
```

How do I count the number of rows the variable `result` contains in the Python code? I don't want to use `COUNT()` in SQL.
With

```
print(dir(result))
```

I found there is a `rowcount`, however it has always the value `-1`.

The variable `result` has the type `LegacyCursorResult`. Where can find full documentation for this class?
The (probably) official docs only mention a close() method:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html?highlight=legacycursorresult#sqlalchemy.engine.LegacyCursorResult

Thanks a lot, if somebody can help!

Comment: Why do you not want to use sql `COUNT`?

Comment: The sqlite3 implementation of [rowcount](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.rowcount) is documented to return -1 for selects, so you must either count the results using `len` or execute a `SELECT COUNT(*)...`.

Answer (score 3):

With SQLAlchemy 1.4+, you can use [`Result.all`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html?highlight=legacycursorresult#sqlalchemy.engine.Result.all) to obtain the results as a list, and then call `len`:

```py
rows = result.all()
count = len(rows)
```

Comment: That would not be efficient, I think the question is legit

Answer (score -1):

I did this way:

first_row = result.fetchone()
if first_row is None:

else:
...

Comment: How does this answer the question? This code produces no row count